# How to refresh Android Fragment v1.3.0 in Java

Tags: java, android, fragment, refresh, release

As of the new Fragment version 1.3.0, refreshing a fragment within itself does not seem to work as it had in version 1.2.5.

The code that works for my project on version 1.2.5:

```
FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 26) {
   ft.setReorderingAllowed(false);
}
ft.detach(this).attach(this).commit();
```

But using this in v1.3.0 fails to refresh the Fragment.

Does anyone have a solution to this issue? I couldn't find documentation in the release notes that detailed any changes that would be the issue. Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried using support fragment manager via `getSupportFragmentManager` (of course if your activity extends `AppCompatActivity`)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per [this issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/180101652):

> This is working as intended with the new state manager as mentioned in the [Fragment 1.3.0-beta01 release notes](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/fragment#1.3.0-beta01) as a requirement to fix an issue where exiting fragment views were not consistently removed before adding the entering one ([aosp/1427376](https://android-review.googlesource.com/c/platform/frameworks/support/+/1427376)) which actually fixes a number of edge cases which can cause crashes.
>
> You can change your code to do this recreation as two separate transactions:

```
fun Fragment.recreateView() {
    parentFragmentManager
        .beginTransaction()
        .detach(this)
        .commitNow()
    parentFragmentManager
        .beginTransaction()
        .attach(this)
        .commitNow()
}
```

It goes on to say:

> You might want to star [b/173472486](https://issuetracker.google.com/173472486) for tracking a Lint warning to offer a quick fix exactly this pattern and [b/165840276](https://issuetracker.google.com/165840276) for adding a first class API to fragments to recreate its view without needing `detach()`/`attach()`.

Comment: Separating my chained detach(...) and attach(...) calls with each followed up by using the commit() worked like a charm! Thanks!